Npm install throws EPERM and unexpected token error for Nodejs application
I am trying to set up my workspace for the Nodejs application. My team is using Nodejs version 18.17.1 and npm version 9.6.7.
With the same version, npm install command throws errno : -4048 and Code: 'EPERM' along with unexpected token syntax error.
Error details:
npm WARN cleanup [Error: EPERM:      Operation not permitted, rmdir 'application\node_modeules\packagename\....'{
npm WARN cleanup errno: -4048,
npm WARN code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN path: 'application\node_modules\...
}
]
npm ERR! CODE 1
npm ERR! Path ....\application\node_modules\esbuild
npm ERR! Command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! } catch {
npm ERR!         ^
npm ERR! Syntax error: Unexpected token {
npm ERR!     at createscript (vm.js:80:10)   
npm ERR!     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
....
....
npm ERR!     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3

Tried solutions

Deleted node_modules and package-lock.jspn file and tried npm install again.
Tried npm install -g npm@latest. This command was successful. Later npm install again threw the same error.
Ensured the .npmrc and .bash_profile files has proper configurations as that of team mates.
Tried to upgrade and downgrade the Nodejs versions as well. Tried versions
Nodejs 18.17.1, 20.11.1 and 18.13
Npm 9.6.7, 10.8 and 8.18.0
Same error with all the versions.
Checked the application file permissions and seems to have full control.
Cleared cache and editor history of VS code.
Deleted and imported the project again.
Have set the npm home in the path environment variable as well.

None of the above worked.Also, my other Nodejs applications working fine. I am facing this issue for only one application.

try run installation from cmd not from vs code, some time editor doesn't have enough permissions. If you can, just rum cmd as administrator.
